# zend form giving error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am new to ZF.i have made a function that basically make a Form this is code

```
 require_once 'Zend/Form.php';
  function getLoginForm(){
$username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
$username->setLabel('Username:')
        ->setRequired(true);

$password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
$password->setLabel('Password:')
        ->setRequired(true);

$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('login');
$submit->setLabel('Login');

$loginForm = new Zend_Form();
$loginForm->setAction('/login/index/')
        ->setMethod('post')
        ->addElement($username)
        ->addElement($password)
        ->addElement($submit);
 return $loginForm;
}
```

this is the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Form_Element_Text' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\phoggi\application\controllers\LoginController.php on line 68
```

line 68 refers to this line

```
 $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
```

Further how can i **add css classes** to each and every element in my form and also how to add **my own error messages**.plz take one element and add custom error messages and css class.Thanking you all.
**EDITED** this is my index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
$rootDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
set_include_path($rootDir . '/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Front.php';
require_once 'Zend/Registry.php';
require_once 'Zend/Paginator.php';
include_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php';
require_once 'Zend/View.php';
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php';
$params = array('host'         => 'localhost',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'    => '',
        'dbname'        => 'xyz'
       );

     $DB      = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($params);
       $DB->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
     Zend_Registry::set('DB',$DB);

 $view = new Zend_View();
 $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
 $viewRenderer->setView($view);
 Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
 Zend_Controller_Front::run('../application/controllers');
 ?>
```

Comment: are you trying use Zend Framework as a Zend Framework mvc application or are you trying to use bits and pieces of Zend Framework? Also what version are you using?

Comment: @RockyFord sir i want to  Zend Framework as a mvc application.i started my app but as i am new to ZF so i have no idea.but my app is really huge

Comment: What version of Zend Framework are you using?

Comment: @RockyFord Zend Framework version 1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what a standard index.php file looks like as created by Zend_Tool version 1.11:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

this along with the application.ini are all that are required to make Zend Framework work.

```
//application.ini

[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

;database setup
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = username
resources.db.params.password = password
resources.db.params.dbname = databasename

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

it looks like alot of the stuff in your index.php should be either in your application.ini or in your bootstrap.php. I think that's why your autoloader doesn't work.

```
//bootstrap.php

<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

}
```

help yourself and run through a couple of tutorials that will help you to setup a ZF app in a very few minutes.
[Zend Framework Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)
[Rob Allen's Zf 1.11 tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)
Together you can get through these in an hour or two but they will provide a solid basis for ZF setup and basic functions.

Comment: i dont  have bootstrap.php.shall i add it sir ??

Comment: where to put application.ini ??

Comment: @xainee khan put your application.ini at /application/configs and create the bootstrap.php at /application. I updated the answer to add bootstrap and a link.

Answer (score 1):

Since your error is happening in 'application\controllers\LoginController.php', it would seem that you are you running a Zend application.  If so, you should never need to call require() or require_once().  The zend autoloader will do it for you.

Your code should work as it is.  Are you correctly setting the framework into your include path?  Your index.php (the real one in your web root) should call set_include_path({zend's library here}) before creating your application object.

Comment: i am editing my question and posting my index.php plz see it if it is valid or not thanQ very much

Answer (score 1):

> Further how can i add css classes to each and every element in my form
>   and

when the form elements are displayed they will have id's and the class will reflect the required setting. For example this a stock Zend_Form_Element_Text:

```
<dt id="name-label"><label for="name" class="required">Page Name:</label></dt>
<dd id="name-element">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="40"></dd>
<dt id="headline-label"><label for="headline" class="required">Headline:</label></dt>
```

This behavior can be alter through the use of decorators, but I'll let someone else tackle that topic.

> also how to add my own error messages.plz take one element and add
>   custom error messages and css class.Thanking you all.

most Zend_Validation classes allow you to specify custome messages.

Another Example:

```
$id = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('id');
        $id->setLabel('Employee Number:')
                 ->setOptions(array('size' => '6'))
                 ->setRequired(TRUE)
                 ->addValidator('regex', TRUE, array(
                     'pattern' => '/^[0-9]{6}$/',
                     'messages' => array(
                         Zend_Validate_Regex::INVALID => '\'%value\' is not a valid Employee Number.',
                         Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH => '\'%value\' does not match, requires a 6 digit Employee Number'
                         )))
                 ->addFilter('Digits')
                 ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')
                 ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                 ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
```

Answer (score 0):

`require_once 'Zend/Form/Element/Text.php';`

Comment: this works but shall i include each class for every elements .i am sure there will be a way to get rid from this??any 1 plz help i am stuck as i said i am new to ZF.plz help